# React component that generate form with 3 columns

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react `Form` component that generating `<form />` based on json data. The field that will generated are on 3 columns. If `select option` are on first object, the `Form` is not generating its field value properly.

See the `Test` class on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/921p9brk/1/). To test, uncomment either one `status` on fields object.

Answer (score 0):

Removing state variable `values` for the `Fields` component resolve the issue. See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/921p9brk/3/)